# in Django, multiple select input just returns a single value?

Tags: django, jinja2

I have a very simple form with a "select" field. For each user in the app it creates an option field, that works fine:

```
<select name="users" id="users" multiple>
        <option value="{{admin.id}}" selected>{{ admin.username }}</option>
        <!-- can I delete the admin from this list? -->
        {% for user in users %}
            <option value="{{user.id}}">{{ user.username }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Now when I try to retrieve the values of "users", even if they are all selected I always just get a single value...:

```
 if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.POST["title"]
        admin = request.user
        project_users = request.POST["users"]

        print(project_users)
```

I just get "1" or "2" but not a list? How can I retrieve all of the values from this multiple select?

Comment: `request.POST.getlist('users')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you subscript `request.POST` you get the last value that was matched with the given key, even if there are multiple.

You can make use of [**`.getlist(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to obtain a list of values. The list will be *empty* in case no values match with the given key:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    title = request.POST['title']
    admin = request.user
    project_users = request.POST.getlist('users')

    print(project_users)
```

It might however be more convenient to work with [*forms* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/) to validate and clean the request data.